# Problem on plotting solution of Schrödinger equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I was trying to solve (in 2D) Schrödinger equation for free particle with random boundary curve (not a rectangular one). But I could not plot it. I am getting some solution by NDSolve.

```
    bounds = {-(y - 1)^2 + (x - 1.7), -(y - 1)^2 - (x - 
      1.2) , -(x - 1.4)^2 + (y - 1.1), -(x - 1.45)^2 - (y - 0.8)};
xmin = 0.9; xmax = 2; ymin = 0.4; ymax = 1.5;

R = ImplicitRegion[
   And @@ (# <= 0 & /@ bounds), {{x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}}];
Show[RegionPlot[R, PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[Thread[bounds == 0]], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Purple, Green, Red, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
 PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

eqn = I D[\[Psi][x, y, t], t] == - (  \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(\[Psi][x, y, 
      t]\)\)/2 ); (*\[HBar]^2->1 , m=1*)
initcond = {\[Psi][x, y, 
     0] == \[Sqrt]2  (Sin[2 \[Pi] x] Sin[\[Pi] y] + 
       Sin[\[Pi] x] Sin[3 \[Pi] y])};
bcs = {DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y, t] == 0, bounds[[1]] == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y, t] == 0, bounds[[2]] == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y, t] == 0 , bounds[[3]] == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y, t] == 0 , bounds[[4]] == 0]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{ eqn, initcond, bcs }, \[Psi][x, y, 
   t], {x, y} \[Element] R, {t, 0, 1}]
p[x_, y_, t_] := 
  ComplexExpand[sol *Conjugate[sol] ] /. {xMax -> xmax, 
     yMax -> ymax} // Evaluate;

Plot3D[p[x, y, 0.2], {x, y} \[Element] R, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u(x,t)"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the "ComplexExpand". Somehow a false assumption is made. Delete it and it works:

```
 p[x_, y_, t_] := 
  sol *Conjugate[sol]  /. {xMax -> xmax, 
          yMax -> ymax} // Evaluate;

Plot3D[p[x, y, 0.2], {x, y} \[Element] R, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u(x,t)"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]